# XMPP Session Attachment

Tags: c#, .net, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I'd need to establish my XMPP connection on the server side of a .net C# web application and then pass the RID and the SID to the client to allow a BOSH connection to be established.

Problem is, I am finding it impossible to get the RID and the SID from any of the C# XMPP Libraries.

Can anyone tell me how to obtain these?  Also.... do I need to establish a BOSH connection server-side or will a normal connection do?

Answer (score 0):

Using Strophe and ejabberd does not *require* you to attach, you can use a normal connection if you wish so. Attaching has the following advantages:

1. It allows you to authenticate with the server and pass the RID, SID to strophe avoiding the js knowing the user password.
2. It allows you to reattach on a later request.

Attachment is described in detail in [XEP-0206](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html)
It's a lengthy but straightforward process, but I have no idea whether your C# libray supports it. It uses standard HTTP so you should be able to write it yourself or use a library (punjab comes to mind). If you can follow python, [here](https://github.com/ggozad/jarn.xmpp.twisted/blob/master/jarn/xmpp/twisted/httpb.py) is how I am doing it in a project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I just blogged about this topic here:
http://www.ag-software.de/2012/01/31/bosh-prebind-in-matrix-and-attach-to-strophe/

MatriX supports what you are looking for.

Alex

Comment: Seems to be the best Library - going to see if there's another answer that doesn't cost £1000 though.

Comment: There is always another answer ;-). If you have some knowledge about XMPP and BOSH you can implement this with .NET WebRequests pretty easy.